# Docker container on Ubuntu blocking outgoing traffic

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemailer

I have a NodeJS application packed in a Docker container from which I send email to `smtp.gmail.com` (using `nodemailer` npm library). The same container (I mean same image pulled from same registry) works on my Macbook, but throws timeout error on my Ubuntu VPS. I tried to ping `smtp.gmail.com` from Ubuntu container using `docker exec...`, and the ping works fine. I wonder what is the problem. Here are the details -

**My Macbook:**

- OS: MacOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6)
- Docker: Version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

**Ubuntu VPS:**

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
- Docker: Version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

**Error:**

On Ubuntu machine I start the container using command `docker run -p 7656:7656 fb`. And the error I get is -

```
{ Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/docker-training/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/docker-training/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:579:20)
    at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/docker-training/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:261:18)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:478:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:302:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:262:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

**My Docker file -**

```
FROM node:9.2.0
RUN mkdir /docker-training
WORKDIR /docker-training
COPY  . ${WORKDIR}
RUN ["npm", "install"]
EXPOSE 7656
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile?

Comment: Added Docker file on the main post. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885668/sending-mail-with-nodemailer

Comment: @Héctor thanks. I have looked at it. But unfortunately I don't believe its nodemailer that is messing up here. I believe its Docker on Linux that is messing up.

Comment: did outgoing traffic allow in your VPS?

Comment: @Adiii as I mentioned, I can ping from the VPS, so outgoing traffic is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The network settings seem to be at fault.
Please try to run the container with `--network host` and if it works, you'll need to alter the docker network settings to allow the connections from container to docker host

Comment: janmyszkier: Thanks. The `--network host` works for now, but the problem is that's just "Linux only" solution. Host network is not supported on Windows and Mac.

Comment: without the code I cannot really solve your issue, but please have a look at this, and other similar topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container